# Typed dictionary with string indexer

Tags: typescript

I try to implement a translation feature using Typescript 3. The final API for the app / views to use should look kind of this:

```
const translatedPasswordLabel = translator.Get('loginform.labels.password');
```

I like to have the translation key (string parameter) compiler checked. I got this part working with a string literal type like this:

```
export type TranslationKeys =
    | 'loginform.labels.password'
    | 'loginform.labels.username'
    | 'loginform.actions.submit';
```

Now I'm stuck setting up the translation store to define and access this translations. Here is one of the things I tried:

```
interface IDefaultTranslation {
    defaultText: string;
}

interface ITranslations {
    [key: TranslationKeys]: IDefaultTranslation;
}

const translations: ITranslations = {
    'loginform.labels.password': {defaultText: 'Password'},
    'loginform.labels.username': {defaultText: 'Username'},
    'loginform.actions.submit': {defaultText: 'Submit'},
};
```

What I don't like is that I have to specify the translation keys twice. I also don't know how to access them in a fully compiler-checked manner. Tried something like

```
function getText<T, K extends keyof T>(translations: T, key: K): IDefaultTranslation {
    return translations[key];
}
```

but the compiler doesn't like `IDefaultTranslation` here.

Basically I like have kind of typed dictionary where the key is a checked string and the value is a `IDefaultTranslation` object. I also like to get compiler error if i misspell a translation key in `translations` or if I complettely miss a translation in `translations` that I defined in `translationKeys`. Not sure if this part can be done.

So kind of a dictionary that must have all keys of a given set defined/set.

I also thought about revering the logic the ways that I just define the "dictionary " and export/check directly against its keys for the `.get('key')` function but I don't know how to do it.

Another thing I tried is storing them in an typed array. This works but I see no way how to check that all keys are defined/pushed to the array.

Any ideas how to set up such a typed dictionary with fixed keys or with exporting the keys to compile-check against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirements you have as I understand them are:

1. Define the keys as a union on string literal types
2. Define an object type that must contain all the keys
3. Define a function that takes such an object and only accepts keys of the object as the second parameters

Numbers 1 and 2 are can be done with a mapped type. Number 3 can be done using the `keyof` type operator.

```
export type TranslationKeys =
    | 'loginform.labels.password'
    | 'loginform.labels.username'
    | 'loginform.actions.submit';

interface IDefaultTranslation {
    defaultText: string;
}

// TKeys will be the union of all keys 
type ITranslations<TKeys extends string> = { [P in TKeys]: IDefaultTranslation }

// If we miss a field or have a missing one we will get an errror here
const translations: ITranslations<TranslationKeys> = {
    'loginform.labels.password': {defaultText: 'Password'},
    'loginform.labels.username': {defaultText: 'Username'},
    'loginform.actions.submit': {defaultText: 'Submit'},
};


// Function that gets the text:
function getText<T extends ITranslations<any>>(translations: T, key: keyof T): IDefaultTranslation {
    return translations[key];
}

// We get an error if we call with a missing key
getText(translations, "loginform.actions.submit")
```

**Note** `ITranslations<TKey>` is basically equivalent to the built-in type `Record<TKey, IDefaultTranslation>`. It makes sense to keep the dedicated name to make clear the semantics of the type.

You can also have a class representing the typed dictionary:

```
class TypedTranslation<TKeys extends string> {
    public constructor(private translations: ITranslations<TKeys>) {}
    Get(key: TKeys) : IDefaultTranslation {
        return this.translations[key];
    }
}
var t = new TypedTranslation({
    'loginform.labels.password': {defaultText: 'Password'},
    'loginform.labels.username': {defaultText: 'Username'},
    'loginform.actions.submit': {defaultText: 'Submit'},
});
t.Get("loginform.actions.submit")
```

**Edit**

In my last example with the class `TKeys` is actually inferred based on the object passed in. You can avoid having to redeclare all the keys by instantiating the `TypedTranslation` class and extracting the keys from it.

```
type TypedTranslationKeys<T extends TypedTranslation<any>> = T extends TypedTranslation<infer Keys> ? Keys : never;

type keysForT = TypedTranslationKeys<typeof t> // will be "loginform.labels.password" | "loginform.labels.username" | "loginform.actions.submit"
```

Comment: Awesome - thx. I'll try it. Just one more question: do you see a chance for making the translation-keys DRY so we don't need have them twice?

Comment: @Marc in my last example I actually omitted your union by accident, the type of `TKeys` got inferred automatically to the union of all keys. To get a union of all key types you can use `keyof Type`. To extract the keys from the `t` variable above I will add the conditional type to the answer shortly

Comment: Didn't notice this. Thanks for clarification. Great help!